# Edge Detection with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera, edge-detection

I want to work with frames for the detection of edges using Android.Hardware.Camera for Xamarin.Android,is there a way to do it ?

I m trying to using OnPreviewFrame for work with every frame, but without a great results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Canny Edge detector*** is probably a good edge detection algorithm. One way to use this algorithm is the ***OpenCV SDK*** for Xamarin.android.

I have implemented *canny edge detection algorithm* using Python and *C++*, which is quite good. This SDK could also be integrated with Xamarin in cross-plateform mobile development environment.

The following link might help you somehow:

https://github.com/TrekDev/Xamarin.Android.OpenCV
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xpand.opencvbinding

Comment: thank you very much ! Do you know if it exist for xamarin.iOS' version?

Comment: @DanBar91 There are some tutorials, which you can find it online. Eg. In this link http://trinnguyen.com/opencv-for-xamarin-ios/.